# creating dynamic textviews inside adapter in android

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, adapter

I am trying to create dynamic textviews inside an adapter. I have a list of objects being passed into the adapter. Each object in the list contains a key which is itself a list. I am creating the textviews based on the size of this inner list. My problem is that the number of textviews created is not correct. It not only gets values of the current object but also of other objects. Please help

```
List<TimelineDetailsObj> listOfTimelines = new ArrayList<TimelineDetailsObj>();
listOfTimelines = userFeedsList.get(positionInList).timeLinedetails;

for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfTimelines.size() ; i++) {
    String reminderTitleString = listOfTimelines.get(i).learningModuleName
                            + " - "
                            + listOfTimelines.get(i).title
                            + " ...";
    TextView timelineTitleTV = new TextView(context, null, android.R.attr.textColorLink);

    timelineTitleTV.setTag(cellElementsHolder);
    CellElementHolder holder = (CellElementHolder) timelineTitleTV.getTag();
    timelineTitleTV.setText(reminderTitleString);
    // cellElementsHolder.ll_feed_timelinesLL_timeline.removeAllViews();
    holder.ll_feed_timelinesLL_timeline.addView(timelineTitleTV);
}
```

Comment: Post your code and only then we can help you..

Comment: use expandablelistview/adapter instead listview

Answer (score 0):

Adapter returns view , so every time getView is called 1 view is returned to the listview .

Now you want to create a textView , so create a textview , but dont forget to add that textview in that view which is returned by getView method .

```
 TextView tv=new TextView(this);   
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                ((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.leftMargin=50;
            params.topMargin=i*50;
        tv.setText(str[i]);
        tv.setTextSize((float) 20);
        tv.setPadding(20, 50, 20, 50);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);

view.addView(tv) ;
```

view : which is returned by getView() method .

Comment: I am adding the textview to a linear layout which is part of the view being returned by getview